# Tooltip Display Issue on Small Screens with Chart.js & react-chartjs-2 - Works Fine on Larger Screens

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, react-chartjs-2

I'm encountering a peculiar problem with tooltips when using `Chart.js` in conjunction with `react-chartjs-2` in project. The issue specifically pertains to small screens, such as laptops and smaller, where not all areas within the chart trigger the display of tooltips when hovered over. Interestingly, this issue is not present on larger screens (24 inches and above).

Here's a snippet of the chart options I'm using:

```js
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    showTooltips: true,
    interaction: {
        mode: "index",
        intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            mode: "nearest",
            displayColors: false,
            intersect: false,
        },
    },
};
```

`react-chartjs-2`: "3.3.0",

`chart.js`: "3.6.0",

`react`: "17.0.2",

Comment: AFAIK this is not a known problem with chart.js; also, I can't reproduce that behavior in a vanilla js environment (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpjcxt6L/)). To be noted, with your configuration, you should have the tooltip *always* displayed while your mouse pointer is inside the chart area. Please try to create and share a [minimal running example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) exhibiting the issue you describe, possibly as a fiddle, codesandbox or stackblitz link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon investigation, I discovered that the issue was related to changes I had made to the `zoom` property of my app's body. The chart canvas didn't know how to handle these changes concerning the tooltip position, resulting in the tooltip's initial position remaining unaffected while its "UI" position changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  Chart as ChartJs,
  LineElement,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Tooltip,
  scales,
} from "chart.js";
import { useState } from "react";

ChartJs.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,

  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Tooltip,
  scales
);
```

This has solved my problem register with ChartJs (Chart).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?